# Postgres Query Shows one Item twice with offset and limit set

Tags: postgresql

I have this query written in Postgresql.

```
SELECT "api_issue".id 
FROM "api_issue" 
LEFT JOIN api_issue_categories ON api_issue_categories.issue_id = api_issue.id  
AND api_issue_categories.categories_id = '1126' 
WHERE api_issue_categories.categories_id = '1126' 
ORDER BY api_issue.published_date LIMIT '20' OFFSET '40'
```

This query returns the following.

```
ID
313279
312740
.....
313953
```

The key here is ID **313953**

Now I adjust the queries offset to 60.

```
SELECT "api_issue".id 
FROM "api_issue" 
LEFT JOIN api_issue_categories ON api_issue_categories.issue_id = api_issue.id  
AND api_issue_categories.categories_id = '1126' 
WHERE api_issue_categories.categories_id = '1126' 
ORDER BY api_issue.published_date LIMIT '20' OFFSET '60'
```

And the following results are returned.

```
ID
313953
.....
312740
313454
```

Notice that **313953** is returned as the first result.

So the problem is that ID **313953** is returned as the last result in the initial query and the first result in the second query. I've verified that there is only 1 entry for this record in the JOIN table.

The extremely strange thing is that you would think this would happen consistently. That the last returned ID would be the first returned ID in the next query, but this only happens when the initial offset is 40 and the second query uses an offset of 60.

This query is used on the front end as a paging result and this is the only entry out of 175 that shows up twice for some reason.

Does anyone have any idea?? I'm baffled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possibilities how this can happen.

Either `api_issue.id` is not unique in the result. This can happen if the api_issue is in the same category multiple times.

More likely though is that there are multiple issues with the same publish date. This way there is no guarantee on how they are ordered. Adding a secondary sort key will help to get a stable order. E.g `ORDER BY api_issue.published_date, api_issue.id`

Comment: The ORDER BY comment makes total sense and is probably the culprit. Ii can't believe we haven't seen this more. We have thousands of records setup this way and this is the first time in years that we've seen the issue.

Comment: There is a third possibility. Another user has inserted a row with a prior published_date and the row id 313953 has been pushed down in the collecting sequence. This might have occurred multiple times but not noticed and one would expect it but not often.   (I guess this is a subset the second case presented by @Florian)